# Macbook Pro 2016 unable to restart due to Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, performance

I just received a 2016 Macbook Pro 15 touch running Sierra and after installing a bunch of apps and restarting I received the error message

`Your Mac hasn't restarted because "Google Chrome" failed to quit. To continue restarting, quit "Google Chrome".`

Chrome then becomes unresponsive and all you can do is force quit. So I decided to do a clean install of Sierra and immediately install Chrome after setup completed to ensure it was Chrome and not some other app. However I get the exact same results. I can't see anything obvious related to this issue in the console either.

Is this likely a hardware issue? I assume it must since I would expect there to be hundreds of google search results for this error if everyone had the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Google Chrome is the only program that gives you this problem it is most likely a software issue with Google Chrome. Ensure that you have the latest version installed - or even try installing Google Chrome Canary to see if it includes a fix.

Comment: Remove all extensions/plugins as well

Comment: So with Canary it works without hanging on restart! I don't know what to make of this though. Surely with such a popular laptop and browser there should be millions experiencing this issue?

Comment: It could be something in your config that triggers the issue. I doubt that millions of Chrome users have got the new 2016 model 15" MacBook Pro with Touchbar yet. It's only just beginning to ship to customers.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is notorious for not quitting.  Currently I have this happening with Messages.  Firefox does it too. I tend not to shut down for weeks at a time.

Excel and Word, will pop up a dialog if you have any unsaved work, and they seem to think that opening a file makes it 'unsaved'

Previous answer regarding plugins is valid.  Try disabling all plugins. Restart Chrome, using Force quit if you have to.

Now quit chrome.  Did it quit, or hang again.  If it does this with no plugins/extensions running, then try deleting Chrome, downloading a new copy an reinstalling.

If it quit properly, then enable half the extensions.  Quit Chrome, Start Chrome, quit. (You need the double quit:  The first one changes which extensions are running.  The second one tests if these extensions were ones with the problem.

Repeat this divide and conquer with successive sets of plugins until you find the one that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, immediately after a clean installation of Sierra I installed chrome (with no plugins) and then immediately tried to restart and I get the same issue.

Comment: Hmm.  What tabs are open in Chrome?  How good is your internet connection?   Does this happen if you install an older version of Chrome. https://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/old has previous versions.  Does Chrome try to save settings to the cloud?  Bring up Console.  See if there is anything interesting there.